# Set or override readonly property of baseclass

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, properties, readonly

I want to make a `ReadOnly` property of a class change when a subclass is implemented of it (ie. the property depends on which class it belongs to).

Currently, I have:

```
Public MustInherit Class MyBaseClass

    Public ReadOnly name As String

    ...

    Sub New()
            name = "None"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClassV0_0 : Inherits MyBaseClass

    Public Shadows ReadOnly name As String

    ...

    Sub New()
            name = "MyClass v0.0"
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get these results when this is called in my main code:

```
Dim classInstance As MyBaseClass = New MyClassV0_0

Debug.Print(classInstance.name)
```

Debug prints: `None`

However, I'm expecting `MyClass v0.0` to be printed instead. Is there a way for me to do this?

Note that I need `classInstance` to be `MyBaseClass` — if I had declared it as `MyClassV0_0` this problem wouldn't occur for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shadows` allows some member to be defined again by a derived when the base doesn't allow it to be overrided (And is used only when the instance is used as the derived type)

What you need here is to make the base member `Overridable` (or `MustOverride` here as the base class is `MustInherit` and it doesn't seem that the base class needs a default implementation) and `Overrides` it in the derived

For that, Name should be a property instead of a field

```
Public MustInherit Class MyBaseClass
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Name As String
End Class

Public Class MyClassV0_0 : Inherits MyBaseClass
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Name As String = "MyClass v0.0"
End Class
```

If the name if the same for all instances of a class maybe it should be a `Shared` field but that also implies you'll access it from the class not from the instance

```
MyBaseClass.Name
MyClassV0_0.Name
```

What you can do to still have a field is have a private constructor and call that constructor from the derived class with the supplied value something like this :

```
Public MustInherit Class MyBaseClass
    Public ReadOnly Name As String

    Protected Sub New(name As String)
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClassV0_0 : Inherits MyBaseClass
    Private Sub New(name As String)
        MyBase.new(name) ' call base ctor which can initialize ReadOnly field
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New("MyClassV0.0") ' call private ctor of the current class
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I get: '`MustOverride` is not valid on a member variable declaration.' in the compiler. Same goes for `Overridable`.

Comment: Oops didn't saw it was a field and not a property as public. Well if you need some validation at some point in the hierarchy it ought to be  a property. Instead if all instances of the same type have the same "name" it should be a Shared member

Comment: Yes — all instances of the class will have the same "name". Actually, I'm used to declaring variables as shown in my example code, and have never felt the need to declare them as `Property`. I assumed there was no difference except for the hassle of writing the get/set methods.

Comment: No properties are here to avoid breaking changes too ; if you have a field and in a later version you need some validation on it you'll have to break the code and change the field in a property (breaking all clients). Instead if it was a property from the beginning the problem doesn't exists anymore ; validation or not it's transparent to the client. And with auto-implemented properties the hassle doesn't really exists too

Comment: @QuestionAsker I've edited my answer to show different option I could have thought about

Comment: Thanks — it works, and I'll bear the alternative in mind for the future

Answer (score 0):

Code suggested by Sehnsucht in a comment which works for me (using VB 2010, currently). The solution is to use a property instead.

```
Public MustInherit Class MyBaseClass

    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property name As String

    ...

End Class

Public Class MyClassV0_0 : Inherits MyBaseClass

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property name As String
        Get
            Return "MyClass v0.0"
        End Get
    End Property

    ...

End Class
```

Comment: My solution involes a property in both the base and the derived ;)

Comment: @Sehnsucht oh — copy paste error. Didn't spot it, thanks

Comment: you should read about [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) to reduces the noise when using properties (unless you use an old version of Visual Studio which doesn't support them)

Comment: @Sehnsucht I'm using 2010 right now, but probably will upgrade soon. Thanks!